# Adding iis 7.5 rewrite rules from asp.net 3.5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

We are interested in adding url rewrite rules programatically from our c#\asp.net 3.5 application to our iis 7.5 web server.

Is there any API for this, or should we just write into the web.config?

Some background: we are developing a hosted CMS that will host multiple websites, each website with it's own custom url rewrites.

This means that we should also be able to handle hundred thousand url rewrite rules - if you are aware of any limitaion of the IIS url rewrite module regarding this - please say so!

important note: we can't use the RewritePath c# method because we are rewriting to different application(seperate dlls with seperate web.config files).

Thanks in advance,
Eytan.

Comment: id like to know this as well.